# The checkbox generated by angular directive not responding to ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

my directive:

```
            (function () {
                var directive = function ($compile, $http, $rootScope, $translate) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        scope: {
                            baseUrl: '@rmsUrl',
                        },
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            $rootScope.languageSwitcher = {
                                toggle: true,
                                changeLanguage: function () {
                                    if ($rootScope.languageSwitcher.toggle) {
                                        $translate.use('ENG');

                                    } else {
                                        $translate.use('FRE');
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            $rootScope.$on('oauth2:authSuccess', function (data) {
                                var html2 = 'French <label class="switch">'
                                html2 += '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="languageSwitcher.toggle" ng-change="languageSwitcher.changeLanguage()" /><div></div>'
                                html2 += '</label>English'
                                element.html(html2);
                                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                            });

                        }
                    };
                };

                angular.module('testingApp')
                    .directive('rmsLanguageToggler', directive);

            }());
```

my index file contain the directive:

```
<rms-language-toggler  rms-url='blah blah blah'></rms-language-toggler>
```

my question:

The html render correctly, however changing/clicking the checkbox doesn't trigger the function: $rootScope.languageSwitcher.changeLanguage()

Comment: May be you should try like `'<input type="checkbox" ng-model="languageSwitcher.toggle" ng-change='+$rootscope.languageSwitcher.changeLanguage()+' /><div></div>'`

Comment: What is rms-url? I don't see that inside your scope

Comment: the rms-url is useless, I dont need it.
@StarkButtowski: it didnt work, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why now. Turns out the ng-change and ng-model inside the directive is still referencing to the inner isolated scope. I have to use $parent. to access the outer model, i.e. $parent.languageSwitcher.toggle